# Getting a Border Control to Have Sunken Border

Tags: wpf

I want my  to have a sunken border like a textbox. How to do this? Is there a way to get the controltemplate to mimc the parent border?

Comment: Do you have an example? The TextBox just has a plain border.

Comment: The textbox in WindowsXP has sunken WinForms-style border.

Comment: It doesn't for me. But I get what you mean. I see the same effect in Lotus notes.

Comment: I was able to get a nice-looking result, described [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11767188/718325

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is **no** theme for you to use, but you can work around like this:

**Using this MSDN model (http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC84967.gif):**

[image: diagram of border styles]

**Here's my recommendation: (sunken inner)**

Just change the height/width of the outside border and you use this block of XAML like a TextBox. Reverse the two border tags if you want an outder border instead. Should be easy for you.

```xml
<Border Width="100" Height="200" 
        BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="0,0,5,5">
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5,5,0,0"> 
        <TextBox Text="Hello World" 
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Special thanks to: [Style a border with a different brush color for each corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796824/style-a-border-with-a-different-brush-color-for-each-corner)

Should look like this:

[image: Sample of border-style example]

Comment: If you are anxious for reusability, then a UserControl that inherits TextBox is just fine.

Comment: I actually solved it by using all four borders. I was hoping I had not to create the borders manually, but well...

Comment: I removed the BorderThickness-Attribute from TextBox, it's not available. Also IMO the two Border-Elements should be swapped. The upper right corner seems wrong to me compared to the Inset 3D-Border that WinForms creates. Not quite sure about the lower left corner either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
<Border Margin="20" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Gray">
    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Border>
</Border>
```

You might need to play with the colours though.

Comment: I was hoping to use the border from the current theme. You know like the current Windows look & feel stuff.